# Heroku App is Not Using the Right Node Module

Tags: node.js, git, heroku, npm, npm-install

I'm trying to test a fork of a node module on my Heroku app. Here's what I did:

1. Forked a node module repo and made some changes to the code. Pushed to my own remote repo.
2. Ran the following on my Heroku bash terminal:

```html
npm install git+https://git@github.com/Nsrose/node_model_updated.git
```

3. Ran heroku restart.

This actually updated the file I edited under node_modules/ folder. However, the error that was fixed with this file change is not changing. Before the npm install, the app said this error:

ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'channel' of undefined (line 97)

After the series of commands above, even though the file is updated on the heroku server under node_modules/, the error persists. In fact, the file I changed now doesn't even have anything related to 'channel' on line 97.

Why is my heroku app still using the old node_module/ and how do I force it to update?

Answer (score 1):

To run node.js application in heroku you need a "Procfile" with no extension, there you write the command heroku has to run to get your app running, this file has to be your main git folder for example

```
web: node app.js
```

So after cloning the git repository, saving your changes and testing locally, all you have to do is:

- git add .
- git commit -m "message"
- git push heroku master

I'll leave a link to [Getting started with Node on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs#set-up)

EDIT: Also your undefined is probably a code problem not heroku's